# How to set-up mac-like accents input on Linux?

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, input-method

When I hold a letter button on Mac, a pop-up appears asking if I'd like to enter an accented version of this letter (like é or ë for e). Can this be configured to work the same way on GNU/Linux?

Comment: You *might* find a suitable program, but in general, you'd get accents using a compose-key sequence.